# how do i match comma separated string with another comma separated string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i want to `match` 2 comma separated `string` in `mysql`,

test `string` =>  `Housekeeping,Cleaning,Other`.

```
|              skills                 |
+-------------------------------------+
|    Housekeeping,Cleaning,Sweeping   |
+-------------------------------------+
|  Housewives,Beautician,Cleaning     |        AGAINST  `Housekeeping,Cleaning,Other`
+-------------------------------------+
|        PHP,Laravel,Other            |
+-------------------------------------+
|   Housekeeping,housekeeping,other   |
+-------------------------------------+


MUST MATCH  =>  All the `rows`
```

i heard about `LOCATE` syntax but don't know to use.

```
SELECT * FROM jobs_posted_by_employer WHERE skills [don't know]
```

i have kept my `table` **online** for query `execution`!!!

**here is my Query**:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1931

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @AlivetoDie, but is is giving `error` for `pdo sql` with `slim`

Comment: Either normalise your data, or don't bother using a Relational Database Management System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regexp (you need reformat a little your input with PHP) : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1931/13

```
select
    *
from
    jobs_posted_by_employer
where
    skills regexp '(^|,)Housekeeping|Cleaning|Other(,|$)'
```

or without PHP reformat : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1931/40

```
select
    *
from
    jobs_posted_by_employer
where
    skills  regexp concat(
        '(^|,)',
        replace('Housekeeping,Cleaning,Other',',','|'),
        '(,|$)'
    )
```